# getting except ObjectDoesNotExist to direct to a view in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I need a way to return a redirect to a view if ObjectDoesNotExist is True. I was trying this:

`except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('create_profile'))`

But I'm getting arg and kwarg arguements, which makes sense.

But am I thinking about this the right way?

Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supply to `reverse()` the values that the `create_profile` view would normally take.